# APIDOC - Remove Sample Request

Tags: api, rest, backend, api-doc

Hey there I'm trying to remove/hide the sample request form from my apiDoc. I'm not using the sampleUrl tag on my package.json config, on the api_porject.json this property is set to false.
But still, on every request that there's the sample request.
I've also tried to apply the param @apiSampleRequest off to my codeblocks but no luck.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://github.com/apidoc/apidoc/issues/984

Answer (score 5):

In my case setting `"sampleUrl": null` in the config did the trick to disable the form globally without a @apiSampleRequest off comment.

If you want to disable only some of the forms you can use `"sampleUrl": true` and set `@apiSampleRequest off` where you want to disable the form.

Comment: Thanks. Great!! This is working

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `@apiSampleRequest`    from each api function
and run cmd -

```
apidoc -i /yourfolderpath -o /yourfolderpath_apidoc
```